# Sensu: client socket input (how-to print an event)

Tags: python, sensu

I am trying to create an event using the "Client socket input" described here: https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/clients.html#client-socket-input

when i do, from bash:

```
echo '{"status": 1, "output": "x.x.x.x/22 [AS0000] | NotFound. No VRP Covers the Route Prefix.", "name": "err_rpki_rr.py"}' > /dev/tcp/localhost/3030
```

works (i can see the event in Uchiwa), but when i do, from python code:

```
print json.dumps(msg)

$ python err_rpki_rr.py > /dev/tcp/localhost/3030

{"status": 1, "output": "x.x.x.x/22 [AS0000] | NotFound. No VRP Covers the Route Prefix.", "name": "err_rpki_rr.py"}
{"status": 1, "output": "y.y.y.y/22 [AS0000] | NotFound. No VRP Covers the Route Prefix.", "name": "err_rpki_rr.py"}
```

Sensu complains about:

```
==> sensu-client.log <==
{"timestamp":"2016-07-11T22:02:21.698967+0200","level":"warn","message":"discarding data buffer for sender and closing connection","data":"{\"status\": 1, \"output\": \"x.x.x.x/22 [AS0000] | NotFound. No VRP Covers the Route Prefix.\", \"name\": \"err_rpki_rr.py\"}\n{\"status\": 1, \"output\": \"y.y.y.y/22 [AS0000] | NotFound. No VRP Covers the Route Prefix.\", \"name\": \"err_rpki_rr.py\"}\n","parse_error":"unexpected characters after the JSON document at line 2, column 1 [parse.c:590]"}
```

It seems that is not the son itself, causing the issue, but the newline.
How can I re-direct every printed message to `> /dev/tcp/localhost/3030` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect( ("localhost",3030) )
sock.sendall(json.dumps(msg))
sock.close()
```

does the trick :)